# Google Tag Manager, URLs with parameters doesn't fire tags

Tags: html, dynamic, triggers, google-tag-manager

I have problem with GTM, everything is setup right but when I use URL with parameters it doesn't fire tags.

http://myurl.com/mypage/ - the tag is fired
http://myurl.com/mypage/?parameter - the tag is not fired

Is there anything I could add to my triggers to make it work?

Comment: Most probably you are using an exact match in the condition in your trigger instead of "starts with" (or alternatively using Page Path instead of Page URL). It's really hard to say with that little info - can you perhaps post a screenshot of your trigger configuration ?

Comment: I'm using RegEx match like: 
Fire on:
url > matches RegEX(ignore case) > ^https?://(www\.)?myurl\.com/.*\.bhtml$

Comment: That wouldn't trigger your example url since the regex requires urls to end with the letter "l" (the dollar sign means "ends with" and applies to the preceding character, or group of characters if you are using brackets).

Comment: Ok, now I just noticed '$', but thanks for your help!